# Create NestedContent Items In SurfaceController

Tags: c#, umbraco, umbraco7

I have two document types:

1. FormSubmission
2. FormField

The **Form** document type has a property named **Fields** which is a **[Nested Content](https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/nested-content/)** data type that contains a list of **FormField** document types.  I am trying to programmatically (in a SurfaceController) create a **FormField** and add it to the **Fields** property of the **Form** document type.

Here is the code I am trying to use to do this:

```
var newFormFields = new List<Umbraco.Core.Models.IContent>();
int i = 0;
foreach (var formField in model.Fields)
{
    string fieldName = string.Format("Field {0}", i);
    var newFormField = contentService.CreateContent(fieldName, newFormSubmission.Id, "formFieldSubmission", formNode.CreatorId);
    newFormField.SetValue("fieldName", formField.Name);
    newFormField.SetValue("fieldType", formField.Type);
    newFormField.SetValue("manditory", formField.Manditory);
    newFormField.SetValue("fieldValue", formField.Value);
    newFormFields.Add(newFormField);
    ++i;
}

newFormSubmission.SetValue("fields", newFormFields);

var status = contentService.SaveAndPublishWithStatus(newFormSubmission, formNode.CreatorId, raiseEvents: false);
```

On the `newFormSubmission.SetValue("fields", newFormFields);` line it throws this exception:

> The best overloaded method match for **'Umbraco.Core.Models.ContentBase.SetPropertyValue(string, string)'** has some invalid arguments

Anyone have any ideas how to store a list of DocumentTypes in the **[Nested Content](https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/nested-content/)** data type?

*PS: I am using **Umbraco version 7.4.0 assembly: 1.0.5885.31226***

### UPDATE:

[Lee Kelleher](https://our.umbraco.org/member/3042) pointed me in the right direction towards developing my own solution in [this post on the umbraco forms](https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/nested-content/nested-content-feedback/76444-create-nestedcontent-items-in-surfacecontroller#comment-244526).  I hope to have time after this project to polish up my solution and submit a pull request to the project.

I basically ended up creating some extension methods that take an `IEnumerable<IContent>` and return a JSON representation of the objects for the [NestedContent plugin](https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/nested-content/).

Comment: A bit OT, but are you by chance trying to recreate Umbraco Forms style functionality? There's an open source alternative underway here: https://github.com/rhythmagency/formulate

Comment: @JannikAnker I wish it was that easy.  In this project we have more specific requirements that unfortunately Umbraco Forms does not support.  I wish they did but due to this we cannot use it...I wish we could.

Comment: Just in case it might be useful, Formulate is now live: http://www.formulate.rocks/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gist might help you:

[robertjf/NestedContentCreator.cs](https://gist.github.com/robertjf/c6d9122d90b4406b19ec)

There's an example in the second file further down.  It was written last year and may require some tweaking; but it should give you a good start.

Comment: this did help me quite a bit @robert-foster.  thanks!

Comment: glad to be of service :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the second argument of the `SetPropertyValue` method expects a `string` and you are passing a `List<Umbraco.Core.Models.IContent>`

Comment: I agree that appears to be the problem; however, when I look at the method signature of the **SetValue** method it is (string, object).  Obviously that method is calling another method which has the signature (string, string).

My suspicion is that I will need to serialize the NestedContent data into a JSON string but was hoping someone has come across this before and had a better tip.

Comment: You could take a look in the Umbraco source code (on Github) to confirm your suspicion?

Comment: I would try just reducing the fields and see which one of all of those are failing. For the moment add only one field: `newFormField.SetValue("fieldName", formField.Name);` We need to know in which property is failing (Name? Type? Manditory? Value?)

Comment: The `SetPropertyValue` function makes a call to the `SetValueOnProperty(propertyTypeAlias, value);` function.

As @JannikAnker pointed you can see the code here:

https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/75c2b07ad3a093b5b65b6ebd45697687c062f62a/src/Umbraco.Core/Models/ContentBase.cs#L450